# json_decode is returning a null value instead of an array

Tags: php, json, curl, error-handling

I am trying to search the keyword email in the decoded data. But it is not able to get the array type from json_decode.

Here is the code

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36'
));

$resp = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);


if(is_array($resp) && array_key_exists("email", $resp))
{
  echo $data_arr[0] . "email: ";
  $content = $resp["email"];
  fwrite($fp,$content);
}
```

The exact error is:

> array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in index.php on line 34

Edit: I figured out the error somewhat. The Curl execution fails due to error ( url malformed). Still not able to figure out how the url is malformed in this case. The url is extracted as such.

```
$data = fgets($fp);
$data_arr = split(",", $data);
$token_arr = isset($data_arr[1]) ? split('"', $data_arr[1]) : null;

$url = isset($token_arr[1]) ? "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me?access_token=" . $token_arr[1] : null;
```

Comment: You should check the value of `curl_exec()` *before* you try to use it. It's obviously `false` which means your curl call failed.

Comment: From the PHP documentation for `json_decode`: `NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded`

Comment: Right after your `json_encode`, write `json_last_error();` in order to check what the error is.

Comment: @taxicala have tried using json_last_error(); and it returns 0

Comment: sorry, better use json_last_error_msg()

Comment: @taxicala shows no error before or after the json_decode(); I think the curl request curl_exec($curl) is not working but can't point out the error

Comment: Try assigning the result of `curl_exec()` to a variable and then use `var_dump()` to see what it returned.

Comment: If `json_decode` is returning a `null` value, then you are passing it invalid JSON or no JSON. That's the only possibility.

Comment: @Barmar have checked that. var_dump() returns false.

Comment: That means the cURL request is failing.

Comment: What $url var contain ?

Comment: @Barmar have fixed the URL problem via utf8_encode. But still the json_decode is not working. $resp is returning false if I do var_dump().

Comment: Then `cURL` is still failing. Use `curl_error()` to get the error message.

Comment: @Barmar done that already. Shows no error at all if curl_error() is added just after curl_exec().

Comment: You did `echo curl_error();`?

Comment: @Barmar Nopes I hadn't. Silly mistake. It shows the url is malformed. But how so?

Comment: Add the value of `$url` to the question.

Comment: Have already added. See the "Edit" code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use `utf8_encode`

```
$data = curl_exec($curl);
$data = utf8_encode($data);
$resp = json_decode($data, true);
```

> **Note:** `utf8_decode` work only with utf8
>
> This function only works with UTF-8 encoded strings.
>
> PHP implements a superset of JSON as specified in the original [» RFC 4627](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc4627) - it will also encode and decode scalar types and NULL. RFC 4627 only supports these values when they are nested inside an array or an object.
>   Although this superset is consistent with the expanded definition of "JSON text" in the newer [» RFC 7159](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc7159.html) (which aims to supersede RFC 4627) and [» ECMA-404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf), this may cause interoperability issues with older JSON parsers that adhere strictly to RFC 4627 when encoding a single scalar value.
>
> <sub>Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php</sub>

Encode arguments in URL is needed, try `urlencode` or `rawurlecnode`, example:

> Note, I added `()` in `? :`

```
$data = fgets($fp);
$data_arr = split(",", $data);
$token_arr = isset($data_arr[1]) ? split('"', $data_arr[1]) : null;

$url = isset($token_arr[1]) ? ("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me?access_token=" . urlencode($token_arr[1])) : null;
```

### Check if send NULL

If `curl_error` return `malformed` meaning `$url = NULL`, the problem is in your code that generates the token, try this:

```
$data = fgets($fp);
$data_arr = split(",", $data);
$token_arr = isset($data_arr[1]) ? split('"', $data_arr[1]) : null;

$url = isset($token_arr[1]) ? ("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me?access_token=" . $token_arr[1]) : null;

if (empty($url)) {
   echo 'URL is NULL or EMPTY';
   exit;
}

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36'
));

$data = curl_exec($curl);
$data = utf8_encode($data);
$resp = json_decode($data, true);

if(is_array($resp) && array_key_exists("email", $resp))
{
  echo $data_arr[0] . "email: ";
  $content = $resp["email"];
  fwrite($fp,$content);
}
```

Comment: Did not work. Now utf8_encode() showing error as parameter 1 should be string..

Comment: this worked to the fact that curl executed successfully. But still have 'Null' value in $resp variable for json_decode instead of array.

Comment: `var_dump($data);` gives me string(0) "" while if I try `var_dump($resp);` it returns null.

Comment: The url is `"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me?access_token=" . $token_arr[1]`. I have mentioned the code for $token_arr[1] above. I am getting a access token value from a file and then creating the url to decode.

Comment: urlencode did not work. Though, I tried `var_dump($data,curl_error($curl));` And it gives bool(false) , string(15) , "<url malformed>  as the output.

Comment: @AdityaDevSharma update answer again :)

Comment: Thanks. Seems like the error was in the url itself. Was spliting the file for tokens in the wrong way. Thanks a lot for the assistance